# sort Json data in php ? Different specific data?

Tags: php, json

This is json data in webservice, I need to sort this kind of information by top to date sort 2017..bla - 2015..bla -2014, maybe sort value "4" or title 2015 blabla.... value in a PHP script, how can I do?

```
"2015-09-11 09:18:11.023151": {
    "1": "4422",
    "2": "asd",
    "3": "aaa",
    "4": "2015-09-11 09:18:11.023151"
    },
"2014-10-29 13:33:14.325827": {
    "1": "5852",
    "2": "shfe",
    "3": "sds",
    "4": "2014-10-29 13:33:14.325827"
},
"2017-11-10 09:18:11.315102": {
    "1": "2323",
    "2": "sfd",
    "3": "sdf",
    "4": "2017-11-10 09:18:11.315102"
}
```

i try :

```
$example= json_decode($result, true);


usort($example, function($a, $b) {  
    return $a->{"4"} > $b->{"4"} ? -1 : 1; }); 

echo json_encode($example);
```

how we can do it ?

Comment: You're converting your JSON to an array, so you need to access it as such. `return $a["4"] > $b["4"] ? -1 : 1; }); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this.

```
$result = '{"2015-09-11 09:18:11.023151":{"1":"4422","2":"asd","3":"aaa","4":"2015-09-11 09:18:11.023151"},"2014-10-29 13:33:14.325827":{"1":"5852","2":"shfe","3":"sds","4":"2014-10-29 13:33:14.325827"},"2017-11-10 09:18:11.315102":{"1":"2323","2":"sfd","3":"sdf","4":"2017-11-10 09:18:11.315102"}}';

$example= json_decode($result, true);
usort($example, function($a, $b) { return $a["4"] > $b["4"] ? -1 : 1; }); 
echo json_encode($example);
```

Comment: is working but how get my $result ? my json is dont work :S why

Comment: The json you showed is invalid. It needs to be a root, either as an object or an array of objects. In case, your json should be an object with several where the dates are the keys. Try put your json on https://jsonlint.com

Comment: jsonlint.com - Valid JSON my json data , i,did my result like u thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed your problem. I started out by converting the json to an array like you did with 
`$array = json_decode($json, true);`

next instead of using `usort()` i used `asort()`.

Asort sorts your array from high to low and works on dates (in my case)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Is this what you mean?